# In C, is it possible to store value in the last position of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, position, gnu

i only would know how to store value in the last position of the array, with the code below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int x[2][2];
  int i, j;

  x[2][0] = 1;
  printf("%d", x[2][2]);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In an array with a size of two elements the first is index 0 and the second and last is index 1.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to store a value in the last position of an array. In your example, the array is declared as `int x[2][2];` so the last position in the array is `x[1][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

The last element in your matrix is in `x[1][1]`; just put in this position. Your vector has only four positions indexed starting in 0 going to 1 twice (for each dimension); that is, neither `x[2][0]` nor `x[2][2]` is valid — they access out of the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of an array in C is numbered as 0, and when creating an array, the size inputted will represent the number of elements in the said array. Hence, the first element of an array of 2 would be labelled as 0 and the second as 1, the third(2) not being allocated.

So, for example, making an array of 4 variables:

```
int i[4]
```

Would allocate four ints int memory,

```
i[0]
i[1]
i[2]
i[3]
```

these being the valid spots of the array. Of course this applies to 2D arrays like yours.

If you wish a 3-large array(Like I suppose from your use of the array element zero and two), you simply need to, as you probably understood, declare an array with a size of [3].

Keep in mind accessing invalid spots in an array might not cause a crash of your program if it had allocated some memory at the emplacement it tried to access, sometimes yielding to funny results caused by these unexpected values.

Hope this helps.